# QWebView plain text document style

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview

In my app I have several places that use a `QWebView` and load the content from the server.  In addition the app allows the user to select a default or a dark theme.  When the content-type of the document to display is text/plain and the application theme is set to dark, the text is displayed as black text on a black background.  I can only see the text if I highlight it.  text/html documents work well with either theme.

Ideally when the dark theme is selected I want to display white text on a black (or dark gray) background.  I have not been able to figured out how to do this.

Here is the code I currently use to set up the theme:

```
if(Theme == "dark")
{
    app.setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));
    QPalette darkPalette;
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Window,          QColor(88,88,88));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::WindowText,      Qt::white);
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Base,            QColor(25,25,25));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::AlternateBase,   QColor(88,88,88));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::ToolTipBase,     Qt::white);
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::ToolTipText,     Qt::white);
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Text,            Qt::white);
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Button,          QColor(53,53,53));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::ButtonText,      Qt::white);
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::BrightText,      Qt::red);
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Link,            QColor(42, 130, 218));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::Highlight,       QColor(150, 200, 255));
    darkPalette.setColor(QPalette::HighlightedText, Qt::black);
    app.setPalette(darkPalette);
} else {
    Theme = "default";
    app.setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));
    app.setPalette(DefaultPalette);
}

// load the style sheet
QFile file(":/themes/" + Theme + "theme.css");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
const QByteArray theme = file.readAll();
app.setStyleSheet(theme);
```

The default theme style sheet is blank and the dark style sheet is:

```
QToolTip {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #2a82da;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

QScrollBar:horizontal  {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background: #606060;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:horizontal  {
    border: 1px solid #909090;
    background: #303030;
    min-width: 20px;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal  {
    border: 1px solid #909090;
    background: #303030;
    image: url(:/themes/themes/dark/sbright.png);
    width: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal  {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background: #303030;
    image: url(:/themes/themes/dark/sbleft.png);
    width: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}


QScrollBar:vertical  {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background: #606060;
    width: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical  {
    border: 1px solid #909090;
    background: #303030;
    min-height: 20px;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical  {
    border: 1px solid #909090;
    background: #303030;
    image: url(:/themes/themes/dark/sbdown.png);
    height: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical  {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background: #303030;
    image: url(:/themes/themes/dark/sbup.png);
    height: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
```

Comment: Try with a plain <html><body>Test</body></html> to see if you can get your Qt style sheet to apply. The style of the web elements, if any, will always have priority over the QWebView's palette. If you control the web server I would suggest to prevent any styling that could overwrite the default style of the QWebView.